# xcode set image name from string

Tags: xcode

I'm sending an image name from a view controller. In the recieving view controller I want to set the image in UIImageview to the string plus .png

The code I'm trying (which doesn't work) is:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *imagefile;
        imagefile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",myColour];
        myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imagefile];
        [output setText:myString];
//      [imagefile release];
    }
```

In the code here myColour is the string passed from the previous page - so I have images called yellow.png, blue.png etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you want is:

```
imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", myColour];
```

Use %@ to print values from objects (NSObject subclasses, like NSString).

Comment: Fast and clever! Thanks very much for your help. Best wishes D

Comment: You're welcome Dave. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it is.

Comment: Did do - you answered quicker than it would allow me to mark it!

Comment: Out of curiosity, when would I use %d?

Comment: It's for Signed 32-bit integer (int). Check this out: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: %d used and for BOOL type (represents as signed integer)